# $2$ planes and angle between them

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, computational-geometry

IF I have two $3d$ planes such as Oab and Oa'b'. If these two planes intersect a horizontal plane and the intersection of each plane makes AB and A'B' lines. then,

> 1. Does the angle  between AB, A'B' i.e. APA' is equal to the angle
>    between normal vectors (i.e. n1 and n2) of the planes?
> 2. Does this scenario is always true, even if we intersect these two planes with third plane which is not horizotal (i.e. instead of XY , if there is oblique plane)?

Please, answer my both questions.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not, in general, true that the angle between the normal vectors $n_1$ and $n_2$ of two planes is equal to the angle between the lines of intersection $AB$ and $A′B′$ of these two planes with a third plane.

For example, you may have two non-parallel planes which intersect the XY plane in parallel lines.

Also, there is nothing special about the XX-plane being 'horizontal'.

Comment: thanks, but answer is not clear to me.

Comment: Which part of the answer do you not understand?

Comment: according Q1, you clearly did not say that ang. between n1, n2 is equal the angle between AB, A'B'.

Comment: @gnp: I said that the angle between $n_1$ and $n_2$ is NOT, in general, equal to the angle between the lines $AB$ and $A'B'$. The answer to Q1 is therefore 'no'. The answer to Q2 is also 'no'.

Comment: ok, I got now. I think I made a small mistake and I should say not n1 and n2. But XY projection of n1 and n2. According to my update, does my Q1 give "yes" ?

Comment: I think it would be appropriate to ask a new question with this update.

Comment: ok, i have post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344626/angle-between-steepest-gradient-of-two-plane