# angle between steepest gradient of two plane

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, computational-geometry

IF I have two 3d planes such as Oab and Oa'b'. If these two planes intersect a horizontal plane and the intersection of each plane makes AB and A'B' lines. then,

> 1. Does the angle between AB, A'B' i.e. APA' is equal to the angle
>      between XY projected normal vectors (i.e. XY projected n1 and n2 or
>      angle between steepest gradient) of the planes?
> 2. Does this scenario is always true, even if we intersect these two
>      planes with third plane which is not horizotal (i.e. instead of XY ,
>      if there is oblique plane)?

Please, answer my both questions.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, WLOG you can move your normal vectors to intersect with $AB$ and $A'B'$ respectively. Then, consider the set of all the planes that would generate the same line $AB$ (it is a rotation of $Oab$ along $AB$ axis). There is a bijection between normal vectors and such planes (because of the aforementioned rotation), moreover, the set of endpoints of normal vectors forms a circle which plane is perpendicular to $AB$. Therefore, *any* projection of $n_1$ into $XY$ will be perpendicular to $AB$ (or equal to zero vector). Following similar reasoning for the second plane we got that, indeed, if the $XY$ projected normal vectors $n_1$ and $n_2$ are non-zero, then the angle between them is the same as the angle between $AB$ and $A'B'$.

As for your second question, you can always introduce a new (local) coordinate system in which the $XY$ plane will be the $\{z = 0\}$ plane.

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: thanks for the explanation, Instead of a horizontal plane, if I take another oblique plane to the horizon, then does the above angle case also same?

Comment: @gnp There is no horizontal plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, every direction, every plane is the same. There is the horizontal plane when you introduce coordinates, but those are not required for the angles to be the same.

Comment: ok, got thanks..